# Program does not pause when button is clicked

Tags: python, simulation, vpython

I want to by able to stop my simulation. I exactly copy pasted the code of the GlowScript documentation. But it simply doesn't happen anything when the pause button is pressed. The only thing is that it changes whats written in the button as text. I also have a Reset button which works fine. The thing with Pause/Run is in the beginning of the code. I also provided the other code details since I suppose it has to do smth with these parts. Because I just copied it from Glowscript documentation(Run/Pause thing)

```
from vpython import *


running = True

def Run(b):
    global running
    running = not running
    if running: b.text = "Pause"
    else: b.text = "Run"

button(text="Pause", pos=scene.title_anchor, bind=Run)

def Reset(c):
    global t, e

    t=0
    e.pos = vec(ae,0,0)
    e.velocity = vec(0,0,-25000)

button(text ="Reset", pos=scene.title_anchor, bind=Reset)


#other constants for calc. ...

framerate = 100



#sun
s = sphere(pos = vec(0,0,0), radius = s_rad1, color=color.orange, make_trail = True ) 
s.mass = 2e30   
s.velocity = vec(0,0,0)


#earth
e = sphere (pos = vec(ae, 0, 0), radius = e_rad, make_trail = True, color = color.blue)

e.mass = 5.9e24    
e.velocity = vec(0,0,-25000)#bewegt sich mit 30000 ms




dt = 50000
time = 0.1



while (True):

    rate(framerate)  


    g_force = g * s.mass * e.mass * (s.pos - e.pos).norm()  / (s.pos - e.pos).mag2

    g_forceS = -g_force

    s.velocity = s.velocity + ( g_forceS / s.mass) * dt #Richtungsänderung

    s.pos += s.velocity * dt 



    e.velocity = e.velocity + ( g_force / e.mass) * dt #Richtungsänderung


    e.pos += e.velocity * dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Run function changes the global veriable "running", but your animation loop doesn't look at that variable. You need something like this:

while True:
    rate(framerate)
    if running:
        g_force = ....
        .....